# Do you know a better way to write this method?

Tags: android, if-statement, methods, equals

I created this method to handle 2 different way of creating alert dialog, depending on internet status. Do you know a better way to get the same result? Using .equals() on strings in if-else block do not seem a best-practices way... Am i right?

```
public void noInternetAlertDialog(String errorMsg) {
    String title = null;
    String msg = null;

    if (errorMsg.equals("none")) {
        title = "Connection failded";
        msg = "Please check internet connection";
    } else if (errorMsg.equals("slow")) {
        title = "Connection timeout";
        msg = "Connection is slow";
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(msg);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            downloadDialog();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });         
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: You can avoid one of the 2 if checks. Just che if `"none"`, **else** (not **else if**), do the other block. Even better, you can initalize the string values to be as in the `else values` and only change them if `none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `strings.xml` for your strings to allow localization (Retry, Cancel, "Connection failded", "Please check internet connection", "Connection timeout", "Connection is slow")
2. If your values represent something create a data type for them. I mean: if your string will report if internet is available or slow, why keep it as String? A String can be everything and convert to something which says directly what values it can assume will improve your code a lot.

   ```
   public enum InternetStatus {
     Offline,
     Slow
   }
   ```

   And a `==` will be faster than a `equals` call.
   If you don't want to use the `enum`, consider using `"none".equals(errorMessage)`

   ```
   String title = "Connection failded";
   String msg = "Please check internet connection";

   if ("slow".equals(errorMsg)) {
     title = "Connection timeout";
     msg = "Connection is slow";
   }
   ```
3. You can chain calls to the builder and remove the variable `dialog` because you can call `show()` directly (If you still need the reference to the `AlertDialog`, `show()` still returns it).
4. You can go with your fantasy and do something like this

   ```
   .setTitle(errorMsg == InternetStatus.Slow ? "Connection timeout" : "Please check internet connection")
   .setMessage(errorMsg == InternetStatus.Slow ? "Connection failded" : "Connection is slow")
   ```

   but it will make your code a mess if you want to add more `InternetStatus`.
   You could create a method inside `InternetStatus` which returns the message (if it will be needed in other places too). But it **highly** depends on the project you are working with. You could an "extension"  method which does it for you just where you need it without put it in the `enum` code (`enum`s can have methods). You should consider every opportunity.

---

Maybe?

```
public enum InternetStatus {
  Offline,
  Slow
}

public void noInternetAlertDialog(InternetStatus errorMsg) {
  String title = getString(R.string.internetfailed);
  String msg = getString(R.string.checkyourinternet);

  if (errorMsg == InternetStatus.Slow) {
    title = getString(R.string.connectiontimeout);
    msg = getString(R.string.slowinternet);
  }

  new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
      .setCancelable(false)
      .setTitle(title)
      .setMessage(msg)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
          downloadDialog();
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
          finish();
        }
      })
      .show();
}
```

Comment: Is Offline value unused?

Comment: It will be used when you call the method

Comment: Sorry i'm afraid i don't understand. Can you explain when "Offline" value is called?

Comment: When you call noInternetAlertDialog method you should use InternetStatus.Slow or InternetStatus.Offline. It's when it's used

Comment: Ciao Marco, quello che vorrei sapere è quando viene chiamato il valore Offline. Il tuo codice controlla quando result è uguale a InternetStatus.Slow. Quindi quand'è che viene controllato quando è uguale a InternetStatus.Offline ?

Answer (score 1):

It really is not a good idea to identify a state/result with a string! you should use an enum instead.

```
enum NoInternetResult {
    slow, none
}
```

and then:

```
public void noInternetAlertDialog(NoInternetResult result) {
String title = "Connection failded";
String msg = "Please check internet connection";

if (result==NoInternetResult.slow) {
    title = "Connection timeout";
    msg = "Connection is slow";
}
```

btw. use strings.xml for you strings like "retry" and "Cancel" (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: is "none" value unused?

Comment: actually you do not need it here! because "none" in this implementation is default! only if the result is "slow" the default is overridden

Comment: Sorry but it seems not to have sense. What about if i remove "none" away from enum NoInternetResult? Doesn't it work anyway?